# os.walk loop is not passing the readout of the last directory in the hierarchy to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, os.walk, os.path

I'm using [os.walk](/questions/tagged/os.walk) and [os.path.splitext](/questions/tagged/os.path.splitext) to generate two separate lists of folder names and file names (w/o extension) located in a given disk drive of a Windows 10 system. For this purpose I'm using the following loop:

```py
import os

output_files = []
output_dir = []

ex_dir = set(['dir1','dir2'])
inc_ext = set(['ext1','ext2'])


for root, names_dir, names_file in os.walk(root):
    names_dir[:] = [d for d in names_dir if d not in ex_dir]
    names_file = [file for file in names_file if os.path.splitext(file)[1] in inc_ext]
    output_dir.extend(names_dir)
    output_files.extend(names_file)
```

At the end of the loop I'd have expected that both `names_dir` and `names_files` would end up as empty variables with all their strings appended to their respective output files.

However, the bug that I'm experiencing is that `names_file` consistently fails to pass on the file names of the last directory in the hierarchy. I've tried different combinations of paths and files to ensure this is not a permissions issue; it's always the filenames in the last directory that fail to make it over to the output file.

The bit of the loop related to directory names completes correctly otherwise.

It'd appear as if the loop was ending prior to completion. I've also tried adding an `if` statement to force the loop to carry on:

```py
# Same code as block above then, within the same loop:
   if names_file is not None:
        continue
```

But this didn't work either and I'm clearly missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're pruning the directory list in-place with a `if d not in ex_dir` filter in your list comprehension.

From the documentation of [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk):

> When `topdown` is `True`, the caller can modify the `dirnames` list in-place
> (perhaps using `del` or slice assignment), and `walk()` will only recurse
> into the subdirectories whose names remain in `dirnames`; this can be
> used to prune the search, impose a specific order of visiting, or even
> to inform `walk()` about directories the caller creates or renames
> before it resumes `walk()` again.

You can therefore fix it by not modifying `names_dir` in-place, i.e, by not using a slice assignment:

```
names_dir = [d for d in names_dir if d not in ex_dir]
```